# Width of _text_ in each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Best way to do this?
I have tried:

```
var listWidth = [];
$('ul li').each(function() {
    listWidth.push($(this).width());
});
```

dummy code:

```
    <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Longer item 
    <li>Even longer item</li>
    </ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
  width: some fixed width;
}
```

But it just returns the same width for all, which is also the width of the actual list item, and not the text.

Edit: I want the width of the text in pixels. Not the amount of characters of width of the list itself

Comment: Add the Whole code pleaaase

Comment: Do you want length of text?

Comment: Maybe try [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/)?

Comment: Wrap the text in `<span>`s and get the widths of those. The `<li>` tags are blocks and will expand out to the width of the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text in `<span>`s and get the widths of those. The `<li>` tags are blocks and will expand out to the width of the `<ul>` whereas `<span>` tags are inline and only take up as much width as they need (in this case, to surround the characters).

```js
var listWidth = [];
$('ul > li > span').each(function() {
    listWidth.push($(this).width());
});

document.write(listWidth);
```

```css
ul {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Longer item </span></li>
    <li><span>Even longer item</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach I'd suggest is the following:

```
(function($) {

  // creating a named function on the jQuery prototype,
  // which becomes a (very simple, in this case)
  // jQuery plugin
  $.fn.retrieveTextWidth = function() {

    // creating a <span> element into which the
    // content of the passed-in elements, the
    // collection to which the plugin is chained
    // will be temporarily inserted:
    var span = document.createElement('span'),

    // 'empty' variables for later use:
      tmp,
      clone;

    // creating a map of values based on
    // the passed-in collection (the
    // 'this'):
    var res = this.map(function() {

      // cloning the created <span>
      // element:
      clone = span.cloneNode();

      // inserting the cloned <span> ahead of the
      // first child of the current node (from the
      //  jQuery collection, here 'this' refers to
      //  a single Node):
      this.insertBefore(clone, this.firstChild);

      // while the inserted clone has a nextSibling
      // we move that nextSibling into the clone:
      while (clone.nextSibling) {
        clone.appendChild(clone.nextSibling);
      }

      // here we assign the width of the cloned
      // <span> element to a variable:
      tmp = clone.getBoundingClientRect().width;

      // then, while the clone has a firstChild
      // we remove that firstChild and insert it
      // before the clone:
      while (clone.firstChild) {
        clone.parentNode.insertBefore(clone.firstChild, clone);
      }

      // once the clone is empty (after the above
      // while loop has finished) we remove it from
      // the parentNode, removing it from the DOM:
      clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);

      // once the temporary cloned element has been
      // removed (and the 'tidying up' completed),
      // we return the retrieved clientWidth via
      // the temporary variable:
      return tmp;

    // converting the jQuery map into an
    // Array, consisting only of the found
    // widths:
    }).get();

    // return the Array of widths to the calling
    // context:
    return res;

  };
})(jQuery);

console.log($('ul li').retrieveTextWidth());
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.retrieveTextWidth = function() {
    var span = document.createElement('span'),
      tmp,
      clone;

    var res = this.map(function() {
      clone = span.cloneNode();

      this.insertBefore(clone, this.firstChild);

      while (clone.nextSibling) {
        clone.appendChild(clone.nextSibling);
      }

      tmp = clone.getBoundingClientRect().width;

      while (clone.firstChild) {
        clone.parentNode.insertBefore(clone.firstChild, clone);
      }
      clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);
      return tmp;

    }).get();

    return res;

  };
})(jQuery);

console.log($('ul li').retrieveTextWidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>A string of arbitrary text</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...okay, I got bored. But, clearly, this is the longest textual content.</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u4om59qd/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
  - [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- jQuery:

  - "[How to Create a Basic [jQuery] Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)."
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the length of characters of text / html?

```
var listWidth = [];
$('ul li').each(function() {
    listWidth.push($(this).text().length);
});
```

Not exactly sure what you're looking for because, the width of all `li` in the same `ul` or `ol` will be the same, unless you've specified otherwise.

**EDIT**

The size of the character in each font is measure by the width of the capital M. In principle you can multiply the font-size with the text length but not all letters/characters are as wide as M. So you will definitely end-up with a huge number...

Comment: why the vote down? the width of each `li` will always be the same

Comment: yes i know, that is why I wondered if it is possible to the get length of the actual text in each row

Comment: yea, if there's just text in the `li` you can **roughly** estimate it by multiplying the `length` with the font size (if it's in pixels). but it's not very safe. so 20 characters * font size of 14 = 280. **BUT** the font-size is not equal to font-width so 280 is definitely too high

Answer (score 0):

If you use this CSS, the `li`elements will have the width of their text content, then your JS should work:

```
ul {  
  overflow: hidden; 
}
li { 
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

Here it's in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgBvJW (made visible with background-colors)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the width using `canvas` and [measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText).

```
function getWidth(text, font) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = font; // important for accurate metrics
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(text); // TextMetrics object
    return Math.ceil(metrics.width);
}

var listWidth = [];
$('ul li').each(function() {
    // put your own font for accurate metrics.
    listWidth.push(getWidth($(this).text(), 'normal 14pt Arial'));
});
```

`listWidth` will now contain calculated width of each element.
If you want to apply the width to each `li` element you can use this instead:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    // put your own font for accurate metrics.
    $(this).css({width: getWidth($(this).text(), 'normal 14pt Arial') + 'px'});
});
```

This might be overkill, but it all depends on why you need the width. There might be other solutions that will solve what you try to achieve more efficiently.

Comment: Getting a canvas involved just to measure a width feels like overkill to me, but it does looks like an accurate method.

Comment: Totally agree. Can't really see any use case where you would need to set an exact width for a list element, but it's up to OP to explain why he needs it :)